# Options of using \ead

Tags: titles, elsarticle

I'm trying to write email addresses in footnote and I use this code:

```
\documentclass[3p,onecolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
%% Title
\title{Title}
%% Group authors per affiliation:
\author{Richard Robson}
\ead{Richard@email.com}
\author[1]{Mat Harisson\corref{correspondingauthor}}
\cortext[correspondingauthor]{Corresponding author. Tel.: 000000000000;  Fax: 0000000000000.}
\ead{Harisson@email.com}
\address[1]{Faculty of Mechanical Engineering}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
B
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]
But instead of full name in parentheses how can I get:

> Email addresses: Richard@email.com (R. Robson), Harisson@email.com (M.
>   Harisson)

Comment: `elsarticle` is for submissions to Elsevier. If you plan to make one, *don't* change the details of the typesetting or you'll get your submission rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following addition to your preamble adds the option of specifying a "short author" using the input `\author[<num>]{<full author>}{<short author>}`. Additionally, a conditional can by used to switch between writing the short author as part of the email correspondence (`\emailshortauthortrue`) or the regular, full author (`\emailshortauthorfalse` - default)

```
\makeatletter
\newtoks\@eadauthorshort
\def\@author#1#2{\g@addto@macro\elsauthors{\normalsize%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \upshape\authorsep#1\unskip\textsuperscript{%
      \ifx\@fnmark\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@fnmark\let\sep=,\fi
      \ifx\@corref\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@corref\let\sep=,\fi
      }%
    \def\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
    \global\let\@fnmark\@empty
    \global\let\sep\@empty}%
    \@eadauthor={#1}
    \@eadauthorshort={#2}
}
\def\@@author[#1]#2#3{\g@addto@macro\elsauthors{%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \authorsep#2\unskip\textsuperscript{%#1%
      \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{%
       \edef\affnum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{1}{\elsRef{\@@affmark}}}%
     \unskip\sep\affnum\let\sep=,}%
      \ifx\@fnmark\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@fnmark\let\sep=,\fi
      \ifx\@corref\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@corref\let\sep=,\fi
      }%
    \def\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
    \global\let\sep\@empty\global\let\@corref\@empty
    \global\let\@fnmark\@empty}%
    \@eadauthor={#2}%
    \@eadauthorshort={#3}%
}
\gdef\@ead#1{\bgroup\def\_{\string\underscorechar\space}%
  \def\{{\string\lbracechar\space}%
   \def~{\hashchar\space}%
   \def\}{\string\rbracechar\space}%
   \edef\tmpA{\the\@eadauthor}
   \edef\tmpB{\the\@eadauthorshort}
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\emailauthor
     {#1}{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\tmpA}{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\tmpB}}%
  \egroup
}
\gdef\emailauthor#1#2#3{\stepcounter{ead}%
     \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright%
      \let\corref\@gobble
      \eadsep\texttt{#1} (\ifemailshortauthor #3\else#2\fi)\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
\newif\ifemailshortauthor
\makeatother
```

Here is a complete example highlighting the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[3p,onecolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@eadauthorshort
\def\@author#1#2{\g@addto@macro\elsauthors{\normalsize%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \upshape\authorsep#1\unskip\textsuperscript{%
      \ifx\@fnmark\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@fnmark\let\sep=,\fi
      \ifx\@corref\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@corref\let\sep=,\fi
      }%
    \def\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
    \global\let\@fnmark\@empty
    \global\let\sep\@empty}%
    \@eadauthor={#1}
    \@eadauthorshort={#2}
}
\def\@@author[#1]#2#3{\g@addto@macro\elsauthors{%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \authorsep#2\unskip\textsuperscript{%#1%
      \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{%
       \edef\affnum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{1}{\elsRef{\@@affmark}}}%
     \unskip\sep\affnum\let\sep=,}%
      \ifx\@fnmark\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@fnmark\let\sep=,\fi
      \ifx\@corref\@empty\else\unskip\sep\@corref\let\sep=,\fi
      }%
    \def\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
    \global\let\sep\@empty\global\let\@corref\@empty
    \global\let\@fnmark\@empty}%
    \@eadauthor={#2}%
    \@eadauthorshort={#3}%
}
\gdef\@ead#1{\bgroup\def\_{\string\underscorechar\space}%
  \def\{{\string\lbracechar\space}%
   \def~{\hashchar\space}%
   \def\}{\string\rbracechar\space}%
   \edef\tmpA{\the\@eadauthor}
   \edef\tmpB{\the\@eadauthorshort}
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\emailauthor
     {#1}{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\tmpA}{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\tmpB}}%
  \egroup
}
\gdef\emailauthor#1#2#3{\stepcounter{ead}%
     \g@addto@macro\@elseads{\raggedright%
      \let\corref\@gobble
      \eadsep\texttt{#1} (\ifemailshortauthor #3\else#2\fi)\def\eadsep{\unskip,\space}}%
}
\newif\ifemailshortauthor
\makeatother

\emailshortauthortrue
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
%% Title
\title{Title}
%% Group authors per affiliation:
\author{Richard Robson}{R Robson}
\ead{Richard@email.com}
\author[1]{Mat Harisson\corref{correspondingauthor}}{M Harisson}
\cortext[correspondingauthor]{Corresponding author. Tel.: 000000000000;  Fax: 0000000000000.}
\ead{Harisson@email.com}
\address[1]{Faculty of Mechanical Engineering}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
B
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice code, which will probably cause rejection for the OP's submission.

Comment: This is another solution, but not generic of course:
`\makeatletter
\emailauthor{Richard@email.com}{R. Robson}
\emailauthor{Harisson@email.com}{M. Harisson}
\let\emailauthor\@gobbletwo
\makeatother`